# ILMerge build task copylocal missing

Tags: visual-studio-2015, msbuild-task, ilmerge

I try to use ILMerge Task in Visual Studio 2015

I get this german error message, see translation to english below:

> MSBuild.ILMerge.Task.targets(35,5): error MSB4096: Das Element
>   "....\my.dll" in der Elementliste "ReferencePath" definiert keinen
>   Wert für die CopyLocal-Metadaten. Wenn Sie diese Metadaten verwenden
>   möchten, qualifizieren Sie sie, indem Sie %(ReferencePath.CopyLocal)
>   angeben, oder vergewissern Sie sich, dass alle Elemente in der Liste
>   einen Wert für diese Metadaten definieren.

Translated Message:

> MSBuild.ILMerge.Task.targets(35,5): error MSB4096: the element
>   "....\my.dll" in the element list "ReferencePath" defines no vale for
>   the CopyLocal-Metadata. If you want to use this this meta data,
>   qualify it, by specifying %(ReferencePath.CopyLocal), or ensure all
>   elements in the list have a value for this meta data.

My solution contains a mein project building a wpf application and a sub project building to my.dll.

I cannot figure out what this message wants to tell me.
Where is missing what?
Can you help?